# Redirection to a page for new customers without an active product WHMCS

Tags: hook, whmcs

Good morning,

I made a hook to try to redirect new customers and those who no longer have an active product among product group 1 :

```
add_hook('ClientAreaPage', 1, function($vars) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/store/adhesion') {
        return;
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['uid']) && $_SESSION['uid']) {
    $client_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
    $result = localAPI('GetClientsProducts', array('clientid' => $client_id, 'status' => 'Active'), '');
    if ($result['result'] == 'success') {
        $products = $result['products'];
        $has_active_product = false;
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if ($product['gid'] == 1 && $product['status'] == 'Active') {
                $has_active_product = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$has_active_product) {
            header('Location: /store/adhesion');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
});
```

With this, the customer is always redirected to the page `/store/adhesion` even if he has an active product,

I check documentation, this is my first hook and I can't figure out where the problem is.

Can you help me ?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answer is still relevant, but here is a modification to your code.

Instead of getting the client ID from the session, which will return NULL, you should get it from the currently authenticated user instead.
[WHMCS\Authentication\CurrentUser](https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/authentication/)

```
$currentUser = new \WHMCS\Authentication\CurrentUser;
add_hook('ClientAreaPage', 1, function($vars) {

$currentUser = new \WHMCS\Authentication\CurrentUser;
$user = $currentUser->user();
$client = $currentUser->client();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/store/adhesion') {
    return;
}

if ($user) {
    $client_id = $client->id;
    
    $result = localAPI('GetClientsProducts', array('clientid' => $client_id, 'status' => 'Active'), '');
    if ($result['result'] == 'success') {
        $products = $result['products'];
        
        $has_active_product = false;
        if($products != NULL || !empty($products)){
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                if ($product['pid'] != 0 && $product['status'] == 'Active') {
                    $has_active_product = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($has_active_product) {
            header('Location: /store/adhesion');
            exit;
        }
    }
}});
```

I got the client ID from the current authenticated user, checked if the user was not null, and then used the localAPI to get the clients' products.

I see that you checked against `$product['gid'] == 3`; I don't know what that is but I changed it to check if product Id exists.

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Steve Brain and thank you for taking the time to answer me.
I have just carried out some tests with your modifications and modified some details:

```
add_hook('ClientAreaPage', 1, function($vars) {

$currentUser = new \WHMCS\Authentication\CurrentUser;
$user = $currentUser->user();
$client = $currentUser->client();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/store/adhesion') {
    return;
}

if ($user) {
    $client_id = $client->id;
    
    $result = localAPI('GetClientsProducts', array('clientid' => $client_id, 'status' => 'Active'), '');
    if ($result['result'] == 'success') {
        $products = $result['products'];
        
        $has_active_product = false;
        if($products != NULL || !empty($products)){
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                if ($product['gid'] == 3 && $product['status'] == 'Active') { // User can have other pid from same gid, i need to check if product is on right group id
                    $has_active_product = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!$has_active_product) { // redirect unser only don't have product active on account
            header('Location: /store/adhesion');
            exit;
        }
    }
}});
```

I summarize, the hook must redirect a user connected without active group 3 product on his account (which explains the GID 3 that you mentioned).

Except that with the old code as well as with yours, whether or not the customer has an active product from group 3 or another group, he is systematically redirected to the store/membership page.

And I still don't understand why because everything is there but nothing helps.

If you have an idea, I'm interested,
thanks again